# Azure Pipelines YAML: Declaring parameters in template file and parent file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am developing a pipeline in Azure DevOps. I have a pipeline with three stages:

1. Build
2. Deploy to TEST
3. Deploy to PROD

In the pipeline, I have a parameter which captures the commit message:

```
parameters: # doesnt seem to work with template use
- name: CommitMessage
  displayName: Enter commit message
  type: string
```

I have a deployment template file with parameters for stages 2-3.

```
parameters: # defaults for any parameters that aren't specified
  - name: environment_name
      displayName: Environment name/type
      type: string
  - name: variable_group
      displayName: Variable Group
      type: string
  - name: solution_name
      displayName: Solution Name
      type: string
  - name: deployment_settings_file_name
      displayName: Deployment settings file name
      type: string
      default: deployment-settings.json
```

In my pipeline, it throws an error (unexpected property) where I assign the parameter values:

```
- template: deployment-template.yml
    parameters:
    environment_name: TEST
    variable_group: Test_Deployment_Variables       
    solution_name: $(solutionName)
    deployment_settings_file_name: deployment-settings.json
```

Can parameters not be assigned at the root of the pipeline and within the template?

For context, here are parts of the YAML files:
**Pipeline**

```
trigger: none
name: $(Rev:r) # Set the build number 

parameters:
- name: CommitMessage
  displayName: Enter commit message
  type: string

# Global variables
variables: 
  solutionName: ALM_Solution
  userEmail: xyz@abc.com

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
    - job: Build
      pool:
        vmImage: windows-latest
      steps:
      - task: Task1
      - task: Task2
      ...
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          ArtifactName: 'drop'
          publishLocation: 'Container'

  - stage: deploy_to_test
    displayName: Deploy to TEST
    jobs:
    - template: deployment-template.yml
      parameters:
        environment_name: TEST
        variable_group: Test_Deployment_Variables       
        solution_name: $(solutionName)
        deployment_settings_file_name: deployment-settings.json

  - stage: deploy_to_prod
    displayName: Deploy to PROD
    jobs:
    - template: deployment-template.yml
      parameters:
        environment_name: PROD
        variable_group: Prod_Deployment_Variables       
        solution_name: $(solutionName)
        deployment_settings_file_name: deployment-settings.json
```

**Deployment Template**

```
arameters:
  - name: environment_name
      displayName: Environment name/type
      type: string
  - name: variable_group
      displayName: Variable Group
      type: string
  - name: solution_name
      displayName: Solution Name
      type: string
  - name: deployment_settings_file_name
      displayName: Deployment settings file name
      type: string
      default: deployment-settings.json

job:
    - deployment: deployment
      environment: '${{parameters.environment_name}}'
      continueOnError: false
      timeoutInMinutes: 20 # 

      pool:
        vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      
      variables:
        # Variable group
        - group: '${{parameters.variable_group}}'

      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - download: buildPipeline
              artifact: drop            
            - task: PowerPlatformToolInstaller@2
            - task: task1
            - task: task2
```

I have tried confirming YAML syntax via online checkers and it appears to be valid.

Comment: Have you checked my latest suggestion below? Did it work for you? If you have published an artifact named `drop` in your Build stage, you should config download as `- download: current` and `artifact: drop`.

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes to your `deployment-template.yml` and now the pipeline works fine on my side.

1. Change `arameters:` to `parameters:`
2. You should define parameters as shown below:

```
parameters:
- name: environment_name
  displayName: Environment name/type
  type: string
- name: variable_group
  displayName: Variable Group
  type: string
- name: solution_name
  displayName: Solution Name
  type: string
- name: deployment_settings_file_name
  displayName: Deployment settings file name
  type: string
  default: deployment-settings.json
```

3. Change `job:` to `jobs:`

The complete `deployment-template.yml` file:

```
parameters:
- name: environment_name
  displayName: Environment name/type
  type: string
- name: variable_group
  displayName: Variable Group
  type: string
- name: solution_name
  displayName: Solution Name
  type: string
- name: deployment_settings_file_name
  displayName: Deployment settings file name
  type: string
  default: deployment-settings.json

jobs:
- deployment: deployment
  environment: '${{parameters.environment_name}}'
  continueOnError: false
  timeoutInMinutes: 20 # 

  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      
  variables:
    # Variable group
    - group: '${{parameters.variable_group}}'

  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - script: echo 'The value of solution_name' ${{parameters.solution_name}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I still see each of the  template parameters highlighted in the pipeline YAML file (error message example "Unexpected property name environment_name"). When I click validate, it says "A value for the 'CommitMessage' parameter must be provided."

I tried running the pipeline after making the changes. The build stage succeeds, but it fails at the "Deploy to TEST" stage without any error message. The logs for the stage just say "Parent pipeline used these runtime parameters
CommitMessage : "Test templated pipeline""

Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: 1. "When I click validate, it says "A value for the 'CommitMessage' parameter must be provided." - This is expected since you don't set any default value for 'CommitMessage' parameter. 2. "it fails at the "Deploy to TEST" stage without any error message". - Please add a variable `system.debug` and set the value to true, then run the pipeline again to check if there is any error message. 3. Please create a new repo and use your old `main.yaml` and the `deployment-template.yml` shared by me to create a new pipeline. Check if it works.

Comment: I tried enabling system.debug, but it still failed upon reaching the the deployment stage without error logs. I used your template structure which worked. Upon further testing, I found that the error was being caused by my first step in the template file `- download: buildPipeline
              artifact: drop`. I am  however not sure what is wrong specifically.

Comment: Did you publish an artifact named `drop` in your Build stage? If not, where did you publish the artifact? If you have published it in your build stage, you should config download as `- download: current` and `artifact: drop`. `download` is used to specify current, pipeline resource identifier, or none to disable automatic download. See the detailed info from [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#download-artifacts).